# What is `self-insert` is for?

Tags: zsh

What is `self-insert` is for in zsh? I see it every where in the prezto configs but cannot grasp what it is suppose to do, ZLE documentation is also not specifying what it is, however mentioning it in some different contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When bound to a key, this function inserts the key itself as an input character. For example, the key `a` is bound to `self-insert`, so pressing the key causes "a" to be input.

From the *zshzle(1)* manual page (zsh version 5.5.1):

> ```
>   self-insert (printable characters) (unbound) (printable characters and some con‐
>   trol characters)
>          Insert a character into the buffer at the cursor position.
> ```

For comparison, from the *readline(3)* manual page (bash version 4.4.023):

> ```
>   self-insert (a, b, A, 1, !, ...)
>          Insert the character typed.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation,

> Any other character that is not bound to self-insert or
>   self-insert-unmeta will beep and be ignored.

I was messing with my shell and bound '.' to a function, then unbound it.  Suddenly I couldn't type a dot, anywhere.  `bindkeys` showed `"/"-"~" self-insert`, but in another clean shell it was `"/"-"-" self-insert`.  The character was completely ignored, even for cut and paste.

To get my dot back, I had to bind it to self-insert:

`bindkey '.' self-insert`